# How to reset Codemirror editor?

Tags: codemirror

I would like to reset all the contents of the Codemirror editor. Ideally, this should clear the textarea, remove all marks and clear the history.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: destroy the instance and create a new one?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
cm.setValue("");
cm.clearHistory();
// cm.clearGutter("gutterId"); if you have gutters
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the dispatch function of the EditorView in CodeMirror Version 6:

```
 let view = new EditorView();
view.dispatch({
        changes: {from: 0, to: view.state.doc.toString().length, insert:''}
      })
```

This code override the current content of the view. This is a short example. Normally your View have init parameter which I have read away.

Comment: Works. This should be an accepted answer, as it's for the version 6 version.

Answer (score 3):

Also, doing `cm.setValue(newValue)` just sets content of the editor without deleting the CM instance. [Doc](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setValue)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var codemirror = $('#YOUR_TEXTAREA_ID').nextAll('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
codemirror.getDoc().setValue("");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to kill the CodeMirror instance, just change the entire document holding the text, data on markers etc.

This can be done by calling [`cm.swapDoc(doc: CodeMirror.Doc)`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#swapDoc).