# Re-initialize codemirror

Tags: jquery, codemirror

I have an textarea that is used to edit CSS code. It's initialized with below code:

```
if($.cookie("autocomplete")) {
    $("#autocomplete").prop('checked', true);
    autocomplete = false;
} else {
    autocomplete = true;
}

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    scrollbarStyle: "simple",
    indentUnit: 4,
    matchBrackets: true,
    hint: true,
    autohint: true,
    completeSingle: autocomplete,
    lint: false,
    showCursorWhenSelecting: true,
    extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"},
    mode: "text/x-scss"
});

$(document).on('click', "#autocomplete", function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.cookie("autocomplete", true);
        CodeMirror.refresh();
    } else {
        $.cookie("autocomplete", false);
        CodeMirror.refresh();
    }
});
```

This works fine at page load as it checks if a cookie is set for the `completeSingle` to be on or off. I have created a selector so the user can toggle between `completeSingle` to be true or false. After the users checks or unchecks the checkbox the editor should be reinitialized without a reload of the page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset Codemirror editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378355/how-to-reset-codemirror-editor)

Comment: No, cause I do not want to reset the entries to blank, but re-init the editor